# Is it possible to pass field name as $variable while fetching data PDO PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

**This is my code :-**
_US is name of One Field in Main Table. It contains numeric value

```
$count = '_US'; $random_id = '1';
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name, :count FROM main_table WHERE id=:got_id LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bindValue(':count',$count,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':got_id',$random_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        try{
            $stmt->execute();  $count = $stmt->rowCount();
            if($count > 0){
                while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                echo "ID - ".$row->id." , Name - ".$row->name." & Its Value -".$row->$count."<br/>";
                }
            }
            else{ echo "Error Occured<br/>";}
        }
        catch(PDOException $xyz ){
        // some code
        }
```

Result is : ID - 1 , Name - United States & Its Value -_US

Problem : It's not generating numeric value. It's just returning field name - _US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super short answer. No.

Longer answer: [No, they cannot](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304).

Table and column names cannot be passed as a param. Of course though, you can sanitize the data manually and use a variable.

```
switch($input)
{
    case 'user':
        $columnName='user';
        break;
    default:
        $columnName='id';
        break;
}

$sql="select ".$columnName." from someTable";
```

You can however pass a `value` into the query and return it as part of the query:

```
$var="SomeString";
$sql="select id, '".$var."' as someField from someTable where id=:id";
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ... i searched allot but didn't find solution for this ... i am trying this strategy because it will reduce one entire column for a country name (i will get it from ip address) & a column name for a country will have it's value also

Comment: @dharm No problems. Sorry, you simply can't do it - but you can pass it as a variable to CREATE the SQL statement - just be sure to sanitize it nicely first, otherwise you open up to SQL injection.